# Web service in python to get the schema information of table in Big Query

Tags: python, google-analytics, get, google-bigquery

I wrote a web service in python to accept the DatasetName and the TableName as inputs in url which will be passed to big query and the fields will be returned as output.

I have used python client for bigquery and accessing the schema information like this, but am not able to get the result as i expect.

it returns **"Invalid dataset ID "publicdata:samples". Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores, dashes, and colons) and must be at most 1024 characters long.">"**

```
import web
from bigquery import get_client
urls = (
    '/GetFields(.*)', 'get_Fields'

)
app = web.application(urls, globals())
class get_Fields:
    def GET(self,r):
          datasetname = web.input().datasetName
          tablename = web.input().tableName
# BigQuery project id as listed in the Google Developers Console.
          project_id = 'din-1085'
# Service account email address as listed in the Google Developers Console.
          service_account = '101363222700-epqo6lmkl67j6u1qafha9dke0pmcck3@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
# PKCS12 or PEM key provided by Google.
          key = 'Digin-d2421e7da9.p12'
          client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account,
                            private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
        # Submit an async query.
          job_id, _results = client.get_table_schema(datasetname,tablename)

        # Retrieve the results.         
          return results
if  __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the data that i pass:

```
http://localhost:8080/GetFields?datasetName=publicdata:samples&tableName=shakespeare
```

**Dataset name** :publicdata:samples
**TableName** : shakespeare

**Expected Output:**

**word

word_count

corpus

corpus_date**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it work by changing this line

**From:**

```
# Submit an async query.
          job_id, _results = client.get_table_schema(datasetname,tablename)
```

**To:**

```
# Submit an async query.
      results = client.get_table_schema(datasetname,tablename)
```